# Make object move in 6 sides of the cube unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello there I want to make my object moves in 6 sides of the cube
like this one
[Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FtEeag8aY-g)
the problem is in changing the direction of the cube I don't know how I should move
any help, please?

Comment: This question is far too broad. If u need to know how to make an object move, please check out the unity website tutorial section. If you have problems implementing specific code, come on back and show us the error

Comment: That looks like it is simply "Snake" with the playing field allowing wrapping across the border and the playing field stretched over a cube. Think of it as 6 connected 10 by 10 square fields, organized in this shape: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube#/media/File:Hexahedron_flat_color.svg